# Clojure.spec keys: separating key name from the spec validating it

Tags: clojure

I need to validate the shape of clojure maps that have been converted from json strings. The json strings are messages of a protocol I'm implementing.
For this I'm trying out clojure.spec.alpha.

I'm using s/keys. Multiple messages in my 
protocol have the same key names, but differently shaped values attached to those keys, so they cannot be validated by the same spec.

An example:

```
;; Here status should have the same key name, but their shape
;; is different. But definining another spec forces me to register it with a
;; different keyword, which breaks the "should have name 'status'" requirement.

(s/def ::a-message 
  (s/keys :req [::status]))

(s/def ::another-message
  (s/keys :req [::status]))
```

I think I could define the :status spec in different namespaces, but it seems overkill to me.
After all it's just different messages in the same protocol and i just have a couple of clashes.

Is there a way for (s/keys) to separate the name of the key whose presence is being checked
from the name of the spec that is validating it?

Comment: One way out of this is to use different namespaces instead of  `::status` (like `:orig-ns.a-message/status` and `orig-ns.another-message/status`).  In the end isn't that the point of a namespace to separate two different things from each other, that are not the same while having the same name?

Comment: I agree, namespaces look like a sensible thing to do, but they complicate the parsing. Right now i'm just doing: (defn parse-msg [raw-json] (json/read-str raw-json :key-fn (partial keyword "protocol")) so that all parsed messages get keys in the same "protocol" ns. If i start having keys in different namespaces this gets complicated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In spec, qualified keywords are used to create global semantics (via the spec) whose name is the qualified keyword. If you use the same qualified keyword with different semantics, I'd say you should change your code to use different qualifiers :ex1/status and :ex2/status for different semantics.

If you are using unqualified keywords (not uncommon when coming from JSON), you can use `s/keys` and `:req-un` to map different specs to the same unqualified keyword in different parts of your data.

```
(s/def :ex1/status string?)
(s/def :ex2/status int?)

(s/def ::a-message (s/keys :req-un [:ex1/status]))
(s/def ::another-message (s/keys :req-un [:ex2/status]))

(s/valid? ::a-message {:status "abc"}) ;; true
(s/valid? ::another-message {:status 100}) ;; true
```

Comment: I think having the specs in different namespaces while having unqualified keys is the simplest thing that works in my case. Thanks!

Comment: How then refer to `:ex1/status` or `:ex2/status` from another ns?

Comment: You refer to them as `:ex1/status` and `:ex2/status`.